# Problem with shared Eclipse project on different Eclipse version

Tags: c, eclipse, configuration

I am using eclipse (2018-12) with a friend of mine on a C project. We analyse code from the **same eclipse project on a local network** (he imported my project). He's got a different version of Eclipse than me (he uses mars). Each of us got a different workspace, however the project folder is shared.

He tried to add symbols (File > Properties > C/C+++ General > Paths and Symbols) and since then the window no longer shows the "Symbols" tab but this:
[Eclipse configuration bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxDNn.png)

The error is this one:

> Orphaned configuration. No base extension cfg exists for
>   cdt.managedbuild.config.llvm.clang.win32.mingw.exe.debug.1048177015

We only **analyse the code** (no editing). As the code remains unchanged on both computers, I suppose the problem we have come from the project configuration files.

Do you have any idea how to fix this problem ?

Comment: share only the source files, not project/workspace configurations.

Comment: You should use some kind of version control to sync your code, otherwise you will face many problems, starting at the usual delays of network shares and code indexation of your IDE